# How can I debug qemu code and the application on the qemu machine at the same time?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, u-boot

I'm debugging the u-boot-spl linux boot-up process. To analyze the process I use qemu.
I want to follow both qemu and linux source with gdb (of course using two gdbs).
The FPGA board I'm modeling has only 8MB ram in place of DDR now.
I load linux kernel image and fdt on the ram. (the kernel image contains initramfs).
To debug(analyze) qemeu, I do (note the gdb is for debugging programs running on intel machine)

> $ gdb qemu-5.1.0/build/aarch64-softmmu/qemu-system-aarch64

and then inside gdb, I do

> (gdb) set args -machine
> ab21q,gic-version=max,secure=true,virtualization=true -cpu cortex-a72
> -smp 1 -kernel u-boot/spl/u-boot-spl -m 2048M -nographic -device loader,file=linux-5.4.21/arch/arm64/boot/Image,addr=0x80080000 -device
> loader,file=linux-5.4.21/arch/arm64/boot/dts/arm/ab21m.dtb,addr=0x807fd000
> -s -S
> (gdb) layout src
> (gdb) run

Then qemu runs inside gdb, and the gdbserver inside the virtual machine waits for another gdb to connect to its program (because of the -s and -S option). Now, I connect to the u-boot-spl program by this.(note the gdb is for debugging programs running on arm64 machine)

> aarch64-none-elf-gdb u-boot/spl/u-boot-spl -x gdbsetup

The gdbsetup contains some breakpoints.
When I do 'run' inside the second gdb, with the breakpoints and step commands, I can follow the u-boot-spl and the following linux kernel and can do normal debug for the codes.(u-boot-spl and kernel).
Here is my problem. When the program is at a break point, for example when the linux kernel is at the start of setup_arch function, I want to examine the memory using physical address. But by this time, the mmu has been already setup and the PC value contains kernel virtual address. Of course I can know the __KIMAGE_VADDR so can calculate the corresponding physical address for a virtual address. But there is no way I can check memory using physical address in the second gdb window (the x command seems to go through mmu too). If I could access the physical address, it will be very helpful for writing some debug code. (In real FPGA board I cannot use the debugger yet, though I'll try to set it up soon).
When the second gdb is stopped at a break point, I cannot stop the first gdb and examine the variables in qemu  code, the fist gdb seems to be just running. So my question is, how can stop the second gdb at a breakpoint and then stop the first gdb and examine the values in qemu?